# Crear intervalo de tiempo 5 minutos Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, busqueda-rango-de-fechas

Tengo esta query:

```sql
SELECT
    count(DISTINCT today.u),
    EXTRACT(DATE FROM today.timestamp) AS dia,
    TIME_TRUNC(TIME(today.timestamp),MINUTE) AS tiempo,
    DATETIME_TRUNC(today.timestamp, MINUTE) AS tstamp
FROM
    `todaydata_view` today
WHERE
    ev = "p"
    AND timestamp >= TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_DATETIME('-03:00'),
    INTERVAL 7 MINUTE)
GROUP BY
    dia,
    tiempo,
    tstamp
ORDER BY
    tiempo,
    tstamp ASC
```

Y arroja el siguiente resultado:

[image: resultado]

Lo que requiero es que la cantidad de usuarios venga en intervalos de a 5 minutos y debería quedar así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Yo ordenaria solamente el **tstamp** en **desc** en vez de **asc** o ordenar por **dia, tiempo** solamente. Ya que de esa manera te ordenara primero el dia y despues el tiempo pero en desc.

Comment: Gracias eso mejora el codigo pero todavia necesito que arranque desde las '00:00:00' y vaya en intervalos de 5 minutos ejemplo '00:05:00','00:10:00' y asi la idea es sumar todos los users de la primer columna mostrando la cantidad de la segunda foto